# How to fetch or read an .bak file in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, database-backups

I am trying to transfer data from .bak file in the azure storage account to Azure SQL Db by ADF. I know ADF doesn't support it but is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have an instance of SQL Server box product, eg 2019 running on a virtual machine (VM) or on-premises SQL instance in order for this to work.  Restore the backup to that SQL instance via a Stored Proc activity in Azure Data Factory (ADF) and then use the Copy activity to load the data.  You will need a self-hosted integration runtime (SHIR) to access the SQL instance irrespective of whether it's on premises or in Azure.

For added value, you could use ADF to start and stop your VM via REST API calls, as part of your pipeline.  I think you could do something like this (untested):

[image: Sample restore architecture]

There is no way to access the .bak file directly.  I have read about .bak file viewers in the past but you couldn't build this into an architecture.  These would be too unreliable or untrusted.