# How to read an .BAK file in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a .BAK (db backup) file and if I want to read it in Azure cloud environment, how can I read it?

Thru ADF we tried to load .bak file into Azure SQL DB, but it is not supporting. Once if we are able to load the data into any db, then we can read the data from the database.

Also tried below link, but not helping us.
[How to fetch or read an .bak file in Azure data factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68471876/how-to-fetch-or-read-an-bak-file-in-azure-data-factory)

Any better recommendation or solution? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use backup and restore like on-prem, you need to use bacpac export/import.
To Export (Backup)
In SSMS, right click on your-database, Task > Export Data Tier Application and follow the steps and save the file locally or on a network.
To Import (Restore)
In SSMS, connect to the azsql server, (my-azsql-server.databases.windows.net) right click on "databases" and select Import Data Tier Application and select the path to bacpac file you saved in the previous step.
Once the database is in Azure, you should be able to connect from ADF.